# Understanding a file parser in C

Tags: c, function, parsing, pointers, struct

I was given this file parser to help parse a file and split the input up into an array of structs. My problem is that I do not fully understand the second parameter and how that interacts with my struct. An explanation would be great as I'm sure I can figure out how to put my input into an array later.

Here is the parse function:

```
void parseLine(char toParse[], struct Weather *toLoad) {
    char *theToken;

    theToken = strtok(toParse, ",");
    toLoad->location = theToken[0];
    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");
    toLoad->daynum = atoi(theToken);
    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");

    if (theToken != NULL) {
        toLoad->temp = atof(theToken);
    } else {
        toLoad->temp = -400;
    }

    theToken = strtok(NULL, ",");

    if (theToken != NULL) {
        toLoad->precip = atof(theToken);
    } else {
        toLoad->precip = -1.0;
    }
}
```

Here is my struct:

```
struct Weather {
    char location;
    int daynum;
    double temp;
    double precip;
};
```

This parser takes a line from my file (toParse) and then splits it up, but my question is how does the second parameter work, what do I pass into the function?

A sample input from the file would look like this:

```
Saskatoon,2,-6.4,0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The second parameter is a pointer to a weather struct that you want to fill with information. You could use the method like this `struct Weather * ottawa;` and then on a new line `parseLine("Ottawa,10,-5.0,10", ottawa);`

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is a so called output parameter. You pass in a pointer to a struct and the function will fill it with the result of the operation. It is basically your "return value".

This technique can be used for example if you want to use the return value to return an error code. Or if you want to do memory allocation by the caller and not by the function that is called.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [ahe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824345/2837627) to see when and why it's used.
Assuming `line` is a `char[]`, you could do something like

```
//using a normal variable
struct Weather weather;
parseLine(line, &weather);
//use weather in your code

//dynamic allocation of memory
struct Weather *weather = malloc(sizeof(struct Weather));
parseLine(line, weather);
//use weather in your code
```

Comment: In the "dynamic allocation of memory" case, you should call parseLine(line, weather); as weather is a pointer.

Comment: @MayurK I've corrected the answer. Thanks for catching it.